# Why is Magento Category view limit defaulting to 5000?

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0

I have added a custom category list mode. Everything seems to be working fine (limit settings are the same as any other category list mode) but for some reason when I change from Grid or List mode to Slider (my new mode) the default category per page is set to 5,000.

When I comment the line in the following code (app\code\local\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\List\Toolbar.php) the limit is set to the new mode's default of 12 and functions exactly as expect. If I `print_r($this->_availableLimit[$mode]` it returns `array(5000=>5000)`.

```
protected function _getAvailableLimit($mode)
{  
    if (isset($this->_availableLimit[$mode])) {  
        //return $this->_availableLimit[$mode];
    } 
    $perPageConfigKey = 'catalog/frontend/' . $mode . '_per_page_values';
    $perPageValues = (string)Mage::getStoreConfig($perPageConfigKey);
    $perPageValues = explode(',', $perPageValues);
    $perPageValues = array_combine($perPageValues, $perPageValues);
    if (Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('catalog/frontend/list_allow_all')) {
        return ($perPageValues + array('all'=>$this->__('All')));
    } else {
        return $perPageValues;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't even ask why you would want to display more than 5000 products but limits can be set in the layout XML (check `catalog.xml` or `local.xml`) or the System Configuration (`system > configuration > catalog > frontend` tab).

Another option could simple be a limitation in MySQL or the memory. Haven't tested this but wouldn't be surprised either one of those runs into a limitation

Comment: That isn't my goal. That is the error.

Comment: And no limits are set in the system section or the layout xmls?

Comment: You're correct, it was a mod to catalog.xml. I'd checked my theme layout directory as well as base layout directory to no avail. Turns out my theme had set a default parent theme to RWD where the modification had been made.

Comment: Glad I could help!